# What are some examples of the part-of-speech tag "list-item-marker"?

Tags: nlp, spacy, part-of-speech

What are some example sentences that include a word that would be tagged as LS (list item marker)?

This tag is used in `spacy` and seems to come from UPENN:

UPENN:
https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

Spacy:
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/glossary.py#L68

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists of items with periods is the way I've seen LS items. Here's an example:

```py
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc= nlp('''The system shall:
1) Reprogram software.
2) Reprogram data.
3) Read/write to memory.
4) Lock/unlock flash memory.
5) Clear memory.
6) Range check.''')
print('\n....')

print("Token Attributes: \n", "token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_, token.orth_")
for token in doc:
    # Print the text and the predicted part-of-speech tag
    print("{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}{:<12}".format(token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_, token.orth_))
```

Outputs:

```
....
Token Attributes: 
 token.text, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_, token.orth_
The         DET         DT          det         The         
system      NOUN        NN          nsubj       system      
shall       VERB        MD          ROOT        shall       
:           PUNCT       :           punct       :           

           SPACE       _SP                     

1           PUNCT       LS          dep         1           
)           PUNCT       -RRB-       punct       )           
Reprogram   PROPN       NNP         compound    Reprogram   
software    NOUN        NN          dobj        software    
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           

           SPACE       _SP                     

2           PUNCT       LS          dobj        2           
)           PUNCT       -RRB-       punct       )           
Reprogram   PROPN       NNP         compound    Reprogram   
data        NOUN        NNS         dobj        data        
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           

           SPACE       _SP                     

3           PUNCT       LS          ROOT        3           
)           PUNCT       -RRB-       punct       )           
Read        VERB        VB          dep         Read        
/           SYM         SYM         punct       /           
write       VERB        VBP         ROOT        write       
to          ADP         IN          prep        to          
memory      NOUN        NN          pobj        memory      
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           

           SPACE       _SP                     

4           PUNCT       LS          ROOT        4           
)           PUNCT       -RRB-       punct       )           
Lock        PROPN       NNP         npadvmod    Lock        
/           SYM         SYM         punct       /           
unlock      ADJ         JJ          compound    unlock      
flash       NOUN        NN          compound    flash       
memory      NOUN        NN          ROOT        memory      
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           

           SPACE       _SP                     

5           PUNCT       LS          nummod      5           
)           PUNCT       -RRB-       punct       )           
Clear       ADJ         JJ          amod        Clear       
memory      NOUN        NN          ROOT        memory      
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           

           SPACE       _SP                     

6           PUNCT       LS          nummod      6           
)           PUNCT       -RRB-       punct       )           
Range       NOUN        NN          compound    Range       
check       NOUN        NN          ROOT        check       
.           PUNCT       .           punct       .           
....
```